# Android: Samsung “Smart Manager” app raising warnings

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have an Android application published on the Play store and I'm receiving reports from users saying that their Samsung device has an application called "Smart Manager" which is showing notifications about abnormal battery usage from my app. However I do not see a way to debug it from my perspective. I do not own a Samsung device, and there does not appear to be a way for the user to report to the developer about why the app is using more battery than normal.

Does anyone have any information about the Samsung Smart Manager app? What causes it to raise notifications? Any insight into what can I do to fix these issues?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact message? I was able to do some digging and figured out the following issue so I might be able to figure out yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402512/samsung-smart-manager-reporting-slow-app-but-shows-information-about-errors

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to resolve my issue.** The solution sounds to be case-specific, but in my app I had a widget that would perform a network operation on the Thread that was invoking the `AppWidgetProvider`'s `onUpdate`. If the network operation took too long, the Smart Manager would raise this warning. My solution was to create an `IntentService` to handle the network operation, then afterward, call back into the widget to refresh its components.

Answer (score -1):

Smart Manager is a new app from Samsung
http://androidcommunity.com/smart-manager-helps-you-optimize-your-samsung-device-20151105/

Watches over resources consumption on phone.