# Samsung Smart Manager reporting slow app but shows information about errors

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have an app that Samsung Smart Manager is complaining about. It reports that the app is causing the device to run slowly but then references the number of errors in a week. It's not entirely clear that "errors" in this case actually mean crashes but it's possible as I think this device might have had QA versions of this app installed.

How do I determine anything about why Smart Manager would show this message about my app? And why does it report causing the app to run slow if it's just errors/crashes?

Here is the full message:

"This app is causing your device to run slowly. To improve your device's perfomance, turn off auto open for this app.

41 errors occured in 1 week"

Comment: Whomever downvoted - Can you explain why? I've provided all the information I have on the problem and other resources online do not provide a solution. If you think this is a bad question please ask for more information and I can provide it.

Comment: I also got same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a LOT of searching and investigating I think I've figured it out. Note that this is not definitive but it's the best I can dig up.

It appears that this message is only referring to an app crashing and the app has to crash a certain percentage in order for the notification to show up. So it has nothing to do with causing the device to run slowly...

The algorithm for determining if the notification should show up is something along the lines of:

```
if(crashes >= ((NumberOfTimesUserLaunched + 1) * 10)) -> Show notification
```

I don't have any information at the moment as to how it determines how many times the user launches it. (If the app launches at boot that may or may not count towards that number)